# strcmp comparison bet predefined and received string

Tags: c, arrays, string, debugging

This is a mplab harmony code, I am trying to received a data at client, I want to control the LEDs from server socket, text "START" will turn the LEDs ON and "STOP" will turn the LEDs OFF, when I debug the code, it shows that Appbuffer[80] has all null variable, ACK[] = last variable is null \0, same in AOK[].I want to know that is it a right way to compare the string as I have written in the code here. Because when I debug the code, it escape this line and jump to server task init(). Please help me.

```
case APP_TCPIP_WAIT_FOR_RESPONSE: 
{ 
    char Appbuffer[80]; 
    static const char ACK[]="START"; 
    static const char AOK[]="STOP"; 
    memset(Appbuffer, 0, sizeof(Appbuffer)); 
    if (!TCPIP_TCP_IsConnected(appData.clientSocket)) 
    { 
        SYS_CONSOLE_MESSAGE("\r\nConnection Closed\r\n"); 
        appData.clientState = APP_TCPIP_WAITING_FOR_COMMAND; 
        break; 
    } 
    if (TCPIP_TCP_GetIsReady(appData.clientSocket)) 
    { 
        TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet(appData.clientSocket, (uint8_t*)Appbuffer, sizeof(Appbuffer) - 1); 
        SYS_CONSOLE_PRINT("%s", Appbuffer); 
        if(!strcmp(Appbuffer, ACK)) //// breakpoint 
        { 
            BSP_LEDStateSet(BSP_LED_1,BSP_LED_STATE_ON); 
            BSP_LEDStateSet(BSP_LED_2,BSP_LED_STATE_ON); 
            BSP_LEDStateSet(BSP_LED_3,BSP_LED_STATE_ON); 
        } 
        else if(!strcmp(Appbuffer, AOK)) // breakpoint 
        { 
            BSP_LEDStateSet(BSP_LED_1,BSP_LED_STATE_OFF); 
            appData.serverState = APP_TCPIP_CLOSING_CONNECTION; 
            SYS_CONSOLE_MESSAGE("Connection was closed\r\n"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.. Plus you might wanna use `strncmp()` instead of `strcmp()` to avoid overflow problems

Comment: So what _is_ the content of `AppBuffer` ? What this supposed to mean: _"Appbuffer[80] has all null variable, ACK[] = last variable is null \0"_?

Comment: @Haris The input is coming from TCP/IP so how exactly did you come up with the risk of an overflow of stdin, which isn't even present in the given code?

Comment: The question is unclear, as per Michael's comment above, and we cannot reproduce the problem. If Appbuffer contains nothing but a null terminator, then it can't very well have received something from the socket, can it? There's no obvious problem with the strcmp calls, given that Appbuffer is cleared with memset in advance. Likely your problem is somewhere in the sockets and communication parts.

Comment: Yes exactly, while debugging the code I got a message tcp rx buffer overflow, I have received the following text from the product owner regarding TCPIP_MAC_EV_RX_OVFLOW. But I am not satisfied with his answer. Because I am sending a text to a server socket, only problem arise when I try to receive a text and compare  to examine the contents of the received buffer, and if the correct message was indeed received, execute a function that would start blinking the LEDs

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem is resolved, I decreases the buffer size to the string which I wanna receives, and declare that buffer globally to avoid the over flow (out of scope) , finally it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AppBuffer has all null because of the call to function memset.
I didn't see in the code you posted, that AppBuffer is assigned a value.
Hence AppBuffer is essentially a zero-length string and therefore when you compare it with AOK, the result is false.

Comment: The line `TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet(appData.clientSocket, (uint8_t*)Appbuffer, sizeof(Appbuffer) - 1);` does suggest that it should receive data and put it in that buffer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this function receives the data and put it in the Appbuffer,  so we are comparing the Appbuffer and the predefined buffer ACK[ ] = "START" and AOK [ ]="STOP".

Comment: Yep, my bad. I missed that.